# How can I calculate the cohomology of this extension-by-zero sheaf?

Tags: homology-cohomology, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a torus, $Z$ be one of the coordinate circles, and $U$ be the complement $X\setminus Z$.  Consider the constant sheaf of $\mathbb{Q}$-valued functions on $U$, denoted $\mathbb{Q}_U$, and its extension by zero to the whole of $X$, $j_!\mathbb{Q}_U$.  I'm interested in the cohomology of this sheaf.

We know we have a short exact sequence $0\to j_!\mathbb{Q}_U \to \mathbb{Q} \to i_*\mathbb{Q}_Z\to 0$, which (after some easy calculations) yields the long exact sequence
$$0\to \mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Q}\to H^1(j_!\mathbb{Q}_U)\to \mathbb{Q}^{\oplus 2}\to \mathbb{Q}\to H^2(j_!\mathbb{Q}_U) \to \mathbb{Q}\to 0.$$

This is enough to tell us that $H^1(j_!\mathbb{Q}_U) \cong H^2(j_!\mathbb{Q}_U)$, but I'm not sure what else I can say.  I tried using a Meyer-Vietoris argument with the sheaf $j_!\mathbb{Q}_U$, but wasn't able to calculate anything useful.  What other tools would be useful here?

Note: It seems intuitive to me that there should be some difference in the cohomology depending on whether $Z$ is a coordinate circle as we assumed, or some simple loop on the torus.  Where does this come into play?

Comment: Since $X$ is compact and smooth, $H^i(j_!\mathbb{Q}_U)=H^i_c(U)=H^{2-i}(U)^\vee$ by duality. You can easily conclude, since $U$ is homotopically equivalent to a circle.

Comment: Ah thanks, this is exactly the sort of answer I was hoping for.  It solves my second question as well.